# ASP.NET MVC2 : Is it possible to make his own model, withou ado.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

For my project, i need to connect to a database who don't support ADO.net by using NHibernate

So, is it possible to make my own model who can be usable by the auto-creation of views of visual studio 2010 ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a DB is not supported by ADO.NET, it can't be supported by NHibernate either.

Comment: I use a database who is supported by NHibernate but not by ado.net !
I can't use the Entity Framework data model, and i search if there is an alternative.

Comment: That's not possible, because NHibernate connects to databases by using an ADO.NET connection. What are you using for connection.driver_class?

Answer (score 0):

If your database is not supported by ADO.NET you must write your own ADO.NET driver implementation for the database before you can really do anything with it in .NET at all. Short of completing that, the only way  you'd be able to interact with the database is if it had a client api that you could call.